# How would I implement a drag and drop function into my android app?

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, xamarin

I am fairly new to programming. I am currently using Xamarin in C# to develop an android app. The app consists of over 8000 phrases which the user will be able to check a checkbox next to any phrase and have it appear on the results page. I have that function written out completely. I need to make it so that the user can drag and drop the phrases around that appear on the results page. I am stuck at this point and cannot finish till I get this figured out.

Comment: Try to look at this blog post: http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-supporting-drag-and-drop-in-an-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give a more precise answer without more details about your code, but have you looked at the Android documentation on [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) or the [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)?

Comment: Actually I went to look at this and this is for Java.  I need a c# tutorial.

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I should have fully ready your post. I've never touched Xamarin before.